# Calculating the expectation of $X=$ the number of failures until the $r^{th}$ success

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I need to calculate the expectation of $X=$ the number of failures until the $r$-th success in an infinite series of Bernoulli experiments with $p$ the probability of success. ($q=1-p$ the probability of failure)

My solution:

I figured $$P(X=x)={x+r \choose x}q^xp^r$$ (is this correct?) and $x\geq 0$ (In other words, $X\sim Bin(x+r,q)$.

So by definition, $\Bbb EX=\sum_{x=0}^\infty x{x+r \choose x}q^xp^r$.

Trying to simplify this, I got to
\begin{align*}
\frac{qp^r}{r!}\sum_{x=0}^\infty (x+r)(x+r-1) \ldots (x+1)xq^{x-1} & =\frac{qp^r}{r!}\left(\sum_{x=0}^\infty q^{x+r}\right)^{(r+1)}\\ & =\frac{qp^r}{r!}\left(q^r\sum_{x=0}^\infty q^{x}\right)^{(r+1)}\\ & =\frac{qp^r}{r!}(\frac{q^r}{1-q})^{(r+1)}
\end{align*}

$(r+1)$ denotes taking the $(r+1)^{th}$ derivative in respect to $q$.

Now what? How can I simplify that further? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Don't you need ${{x+r-1} \choose x}$ instead since the last trial must always end up with a success?

Comment: Interesting. I think you are right.

Comment: Regardless I think it is easiest to approach this with saying $X=Y_1+\cdots+Y_r$ where $Y_i$ are number of failures untill the first success (which are geometrically distributed). And by linearlity $EX=EY_1+\cdots+EY_r=rEY_1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N(r)$ be the expected number of trials until the $r^{th}$ success, and $p$ the probability of success. Make one trial. This gives:$$N(r)=1+(1-p)N(r)+pN(r-1)$$Where the $1$ is for the trial and the other terms represent failure and success.

It is trivial that $N(0)=0$ and rearranging the formula gives $N(r)=N(r-1)+\frac 1p$ whence $N(r)=\frac rp$. Now let $F(r)$ be the number of failures with $$F(r)=N(r)-r=\frac rp-r=\frac {r(1-p)}p$$

Answer (score 4):

The random variable $X$ you are studying has the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with parameters $r$ and $1-p$ (there are several notations, see the link). There are also several ways to calculate its expected value, which should be equal to $$E[X]=\frac{r(1-p)}{p}=r\left(\frac1p-1\right)$$
One way to obtain this, is to see that you sum up $r$-times the geometric distribution (failures to the first success). Another proof, close to your approach is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Expectation). Be careful to interpret the parameters correctly because you refer to failures and they refer to successes.

Comment: First, thanks for a great answer.
If I sum r times the geometric distribution, I get $\Bbb{E}X=\frac rp$. Where does the minus one come from?

Comment: It looks like you are refering to a geometric distribution where $X=x$ means a success on the $x+1$ trial? I thought the geometric distribution counts failures to a success on the $x$ trial. Which is the common definition?

Comment: There are also different definitions for the geometric. It can either start from x=0 or  from x=1. I refer to the one starting from 0.